# Assigning an int to a char with two different outputs

Tags: c++

I was wondering Why these two codes give different outputs?

```
int main()
{
    char a;
    a = 50;
    printf("%d \n\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This one gives 50 as output.

```
int main()
{
    char a;
    a = 50;
    cout << "Test : " << a << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

while this one outputs 2...

Comment: `%d` is to print `int`, you probably want `%c`.

Comment: The 51st ASCII character is `2`. That's what's being printed if you try to print individual characters (`char`). Edit: Thanks Jarod :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing variables when you create them. Change `char a; a = 50;` to `char a = 50;`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the first example outputs 50 is because the `printf` is expecting a integer specifced with `%d`, change this to `%c` and it will output 2 which has an ASCII value of 50.

The second example outputs 2 as you have defined `a` as a `char`, meaning it will look up the ASCII value.

You can have a look at ASCII values of different symbols [here](https://ascii.cl/).

Answer (score 2):

Reason for the first code outputs 50 is that printf is expecting a integer (%d).

But in case of `cout` it outputs 2 because it is defined as `char`, That makes `cout` treat it as char and 50 is ASCII code of 2.

A code like this can give correct output:

```
std::cout <<(int)a;
```

OR more better way :

```
std::cout <<static_cast<int>(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

While `char` can be used as a small integer, for the output operator `<<` it's only a character, and will print the `char` value as a character in whatever encoding is used.

With your `printf` call you explicitly say that you want to print the value as an `int` value (using the `"%d"` format). If you want to do the same with `std::cout` and `<<` then you also need to explicitly say so:

```
std::cout << "Test : " << static_cast<int>(a) << "\n\n";
```

If you want the `printf` call to print the *character* encoded by the value `50`, then you need to use the `"%c"` format:

```
printf("Test : %c\n\n", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Characters (chars) are stored as numerical values according to the ASCII table.

'2' as a char has a numerical value of 50 on that table.

when you use `printf` to output something, you do so with the help of format specifiers (they specify which format to use: char, integer, ..etc).

- Using `%d` will output the numerical value of your char variable as an integer.
- Using `%c` will output your variable as a char.
- Finally, using `cout` instead of `printf` will default to outputting according to the type of the variable, which is a char here.